# Upgrading Django from 1.1 to 1.2

Tags: python, django, virtualenv

I've an Ubuntu server with Nginx  and Django 1.1 installed.  On the developer's local he had 1.2 and it has some features (smart if) that are breaking now on my dev server. I need to upgrade to 1.2.

This is pretty much my first proper django/python project I'm involved in so I'm feeling my way into it. What I want to do is upgrade. There are a lot of extra packages that are used in the app e.g. south, pagination, registration etc...

```
/var/www/env/example.com/lib/python2.6/site-packages
```

I wasn't the one who originally installed it. this is what i see in that folder.

```
/var/www/env/example.com/lib/python2.6/site-packages$ ls
Crypto                               django                                pycrypto-2.0.1-py2.6.egg-info
Django-1.1.1-py2.6.egg-info          django-avatar.egg-link                     registration
Fabric-0.9.0-py2.6.egg-info          django_avatar-1.0.5-py2.6.egg-info         setuptools-0.6c9-py2.6.egg
MySQL_python-1.2.3c1-py2.6.egg-info  django_countries                           setuptools.pth
MySQLdb                              django_countries-1.0.4-py2.6.egg-info      simplejson
PIL                                  django_debug_toolbar-0.8.3-py2.6.egg-info  simplejson-2.1.1-py2.6.egg-info
PIL.pth                              django_pagination-1.0.7-py2.6.egg-info     south
South-0.7.2-py2.6.egg-info           django_registration-0.7-py2.6.egg-info     stdimage
_mysql.so                            easy-install.pth                           virtualenvwrapper
_mysql_exceptions.py                 example                                    virtualenvwrapper-1.25-py2.6.egg-info
_mysql_exceptions.pyc                fabric                                     yolk
avatar                               pagination                                 yolk- 0.4.1-py2.6.egg-info
debug_toolbar                        paramiko
```

Now the docs mention something about if installed using egg there is a different upgrade process to if it's installed manually?

I do see mention of egg files here so how do I proceed to upgrade Django 1.1 to 1.2.

Virtualenv

We use virtualenv to create a "container" for the site. i.e. so we can use a separate set of modules than the system uses.

In the local docs this is mentioned

We use pip to install modules:

This needs to be run outside of the virtualenv (i.e. when we don't have the example.com in the prompt)

```
$ pip -E /var/www/env/example.com install <modulename>
```

So Can I use pip to safely upgrade Django or what is my best way to upgrade?

```
$yolk -l
Django          - 1.1.1        - active  
Fabric          - 0.9.0        - active
MySQL-python    - 1.2.3c1      - active
PIL             - 1.1.7        - active
Python          - 2.6.4rc2     - active development (/usr/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload)
South           - 0.7.2        - active
django-avatar   - 1.0.5        - non-active
django-avatar   - 1.1a5        - active development (/var/www/env/example.com/src/avatar)
django-countries - 1.0.4        - active
django-debug-toolbar - 0.8.3        - active
django-pagination - 1.0.7        - active
django-registration - 0.7          - active
pycrypto        - 2.0.1        - active
setuptools      - 0.6c9        - active
simplejson      - 2.1.1        - active
virtualenvwrapper - 1.25         - active
wsgiref         - 0.1.2        - active development (/usr/lib/python2.6)
yolk            - 0.4.1        - active
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pip -E /var/www/env/example.com install --upgrade django` will work properly and upgrade the django installation, however you may want to read the release notes for django 1.2 and be aware of any backwards incompatible changes that may break your code. Also, you may want to do this on a dev server first and run any tests you may have before deployment as any code you have that relies on internal api or implementation may become invalid.

I'm not trying to scare you off, quite the opposite: 1.2 is a great release! Just be sure to follow standard testing procedure before putting anything into production ;)